# p-values unstable using quantreg::rq in R

Tags: r, regression, time-series, p-value, quantile-regression

Using R, I m performing a backtest on a time series by using quantile regression (quantreg::rq) on a number of features.
These features are selected based on a condition such as p-values <= 5%.

If I run the routine multiple times, I always end up with the same betas/coefficients on the features, however p-values are unstables, and this happens ceteris paribus!
Ex: for feature 1, there might be the case that it is selected on a first trial and then it is dropped because p values are, respectively, 0.049 and 0.0536.

Nothing has changed in the input DF (checked multiple times)!
This happens still when I set a specific set.seed.

Does it relate to some specific random sampling used to determine the level of significance automatically by R?

Tks

Comment: We're gonna need to see some code to reproduce this.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of the instability of feature selection and a drawback of the threshold-based approach that you take.

There’s basically no difference between the $0.049$ and $0.0536$ p-values you give, yet your approach to feature selection treats those as dramatically different.

It is typical to see instability in feature selection. Frank Harrell discusses that in a [keynote address](https://youtube.com/watch?v=DF1WsYZ94Es), starting around the 16:30 mark.

Comment: But that should still yield the same results on different runs on the *same* data, not different p-values, which the OP is asking about...

Comment: Hi all, thanks for your comment. The question has been asked on Stack overflow as it is off-topics on stackexchange. You can find the link here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75671414/quantregrq-in-r-provides-unstable-p-values